# How to convert this chm file to pdf?

Tags: pdf, calibre

I want to convert [a chm file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8nhvxs0yegkoddn/Voice__Data_Communications_Handbook%20by%20Bates.chm) to a pdf file.
Calibre's command ebook-convert only converts the first 7 pages of the chm file into a pdf file, while the chm file has much more pages. How can I convert the whole chm file into a pdf file? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try converting the CHM to, say, EPUB, and then convert the EPUB to PDF.
2. The lame time-consuming method: open up the CHM, copy-paste the contents by hand in your favorite word processor of choice and then save it as PDF. If that's not possible, save as DOC and convert (or print) it to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

[online convert file](http://www.zamzar.com/convert/chm-to-pdf/)

There are also some free software available that can do this stuff easily

[Software](http://cmstopdf.com)
You can find more on google

Comment: the online one doesn't work.

Comment: https://cloudconvert.com/chm-to-pdf

Comment: Not work. Have you tried the file on any link your mentioned before recommending it?

Comment: Yes! @Tim a while ago i was tried such stuffs

Comment: please read my post, which says the output from the methods I have tried (including yours) are only first a few pages of the original chm file. I also gave the link to my chm file for you to try before posting useless methods.